Control for multiple comparisons
I want to select a subset of words that are specific to students and gender. I have therefore let participants rate words according to how "student-like" and "female-like" they are. Every word comes in a pair (one specific and one control word; eg. "women" and "woven"). For every word I have 2 ratings (student-like and gender-like), so 4 ratings for a pair. I have 100 pairs in total, where half has a specific gender word, half a specific student word.
I know want to test that the specific word is specific for its own category but not the other category (i.e., compare ratings for all pairs). I have run an LME model and an ANOVA and get the expected effects that supposedly student words are rated higher on the attribute "student." However, I want to select the highest rated 30 specific words (with partners) but also ensure that they are only specific for their own category--i.e., women should be specific for the gender category but have significantly lower ratings with respect to being student-ish as well as being more female than woven. Also woven and women should be equally student-like since they should work as a control in the category not of interest. I could obviously run multiple paired t-tests. What would you do?
Best!

If you want to see if two words are the same (or at least similar) on a given scale, then you can use TOST (two one sided t tests), this is one kind of equivalence test. You would have to state how small a difference counts as the same.
The usual t-tests or similar will not tell you this.
So, find the 30 highest on one category and then you can do TOST on the other category.
This assumes that t-tests are appropriate. You have already assumed this by doing ANOVA. But it might depend on how the ratings were done. If they are on some sort of Likert scale, then it's debatable whether they are, you might want some nonparametric test.
But ... do you need any test at all?
Why not just take the 30 highest on one category and then just look at the other? You certainly don't need a test that the 30 highest are different from the rest on the scale you've used, and you may be able to just look at the other scale and say "they are very similar". Because if you do a test, then you have to decide what to do if the test fails.
